# sam local invoke does not work with symlink

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cdk, aws-sam, yarn-workspaces

I am building a typescript project with AWS CDK and SAM.

I am trying to setup a backend where I have several lambda functions which share a common lib (which will ultimately talk to dynamo-db).

I created a very simple demo with one `hello-world` lambda importing from one common `my-lib` package (using yarn workspaces).
https://github.com/ziggy6792/aws-cdk-lambda-shared-package
I am using yarn workspaces to share my common `my-lib` library with my `hello-world` lambda

If I deploy this stack to AWS and run my `hello-world` lambda (by testing from the AWS console) it works! (It successfully imports `my-lib` does not error).

However I can't invoke my lambda function locally.

I have tried to use this method (which I found [here](https://egghead.io/lessons/aws-run-lambda-functions-built-with-cdk-locally-using-aws-sam)) to mock locally (this method works fine when I don't import my common `my-lib`).

- `cdk synth --no-staging > template.yml` (to find the logical lambda function id = `HelloWorldLambda5A02458E`)
- `sam local invoke HelloWorldLambda5A02458E`

But I get an error

```
{"errorType":"Runtime.ImportModuleError","errorMessage":"Error: Cannot find module 'my-lib/MyLib'\nRequire stack:\n- /var/task/index.js\n- /var/runtime/UserFunction.js\n- /var/runtime/index.js"}
```

It seems `sam local invoke` does not like my [local dependency](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lF6vD.png) which is created as a symlink by yarn workspaces. If I replace the synlink `my-lib` with a hard copy of the `my-lib` package then the code runs fine locally. (But I don't want to so this every-time I want to run locally)

#### My question is

1. How can I invoke my `hello-world` lambda function locally?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Did you find out anything here?  I have a similar problem with installing local npm packages.